# How to use mod_rewrite and edit URL path?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I apologize to ask such a question, there's hundreds of them all around, and I wouldn't ask if I didn't need to understand. I've tried countless times on .htaccess but unable to make it work, I'm also testing on local server but I'm sure mod_rewrite is on, so should be errors I'm making.

I'm currently trying to change m URL from

`example.com/article.php?article_id=article-id-goes-here&article_title=article-title-goes-here`

to

`example.com/article/75/article-title-goes-here`

The latest code I've tried was the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ webroot/article.php?article_id=$1&article_title=$2 [QSA,L]
```

My folder structure currently stands as

```
blog/

   libraries/
      articleClass 
          articleClass.php

   webroot/
      css/
      images/
      js/

   .htaccess
```

I forward everything to webroot as that's my index page.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra slash at the end of your pattern that isn't present in the URL that you say you are using:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ webroot/article.php?article_id=$1&article_title=$2 [QSA,L]
```

You can make is optional by adding a `?` after it.

Answer (score 0):

> example.com/article.php?article_id=article-id-goes-here&article_title=article-title-goes-here
>
> to
>
> example.com/article/75/article-title-goes-here

Try this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ webroot/article.php?article_id=$1&article_title=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```